# Permute each row of a square matrix to obtain the maximum number of duplicates in each column

Tags: algorithms

I have $n\times n$ matrix of non-negative integers $a_{ij}$. Let $S:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}_+\mapsto\mathbb{R}_+$ be the following function:
$$S(A)=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k>i}\large\mathbb{1}_{\{a_{ij}=a_{kj}\}},$$
where $\mathbb{1}$ denotes the indicator function.

I would like to find a permutation $\sigma$ of the rows of $A$ (row-wise permutation) such that $S(\sigma(A))$ is maximized.

**Note** A permutation here is row-wise meaning that it permutes the values in each row and further, different permutations can be used in each row of the matrix.

The function $S(A)$ can be seen as
$$S(A)=\sum_{j=1}^ns_j,$$ with $$s_j=\sum_{k>i}\large\mathbb{1}_{\{a_{ij}=a_{kj}\}},$$ and $s_j$ represents the number of duplicates in column $j$. So what I am trying to do is to permute the rows of $A$ to obtain a new matrix that have the maximum numbers of duplicates in each column.

How can we solve this problem?

My solution so far is to sort each row, which is an $O(n^2\lg n)$ algorithm that does not necessarily gives the maximum.

Comment: Permuting the rows doesn't change $S(A)$.  Have I misunderstood something?  Is there something missing from the statement of the problem?  I'm not sure what you mean by sorting each row or how that is expressed as a permutation of the rows.  Do you perhaps mean permuting the values in each row?  If so, do you have to use the same permutation for all rows, or can you use a different permutation in each row?

Comment: Yes, as you suggested, I meant permuting the values in each row and different permutations are used in each row.

Comment: Please [edit] the question.  Don't leave clarifications in the comments, revise the question so it is clear what you are asking, and so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.